# How to show the "Back" in the header of React Native for the immediately previous screen only in multiple Stacks?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

When you have multiple layers of stacks for React Navigation, how do I set up the screen headers so that when you press `Back`, it only goes one step backward.  For example, when we have Screen A -> Screen B -> Screen C, how do we set up the header so that once the user gets to Screen C, the header for Screen A is hidden, and only the header for Screen B is shown?

```js
Profile: {
    screen: createStackNavigator({
        Profile: {
            screen: ProfileScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                header: null,
            }
        },
        MyItems: {
            screen: createStackNavigator({
                MyItems: {
                    screen: MyItemsScreen,   
                    navigationOptions: {
                        header: null,
                    }
                },
                PostingDetail: {
                    screen: PostingDetailScreen,
                    navigationOptions: {
                        header: null,
                    }
                },
            })
        },
    }),
```

This shows the `Back` to take the user back to the first screen Screen A, which is `Profile` in this case, from Screen C, `PostingDetail`, but doesn't take Screen C back to Screen B.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's hard to understand. Can you show me the video?

Answer (score 0):

this possibility can occur also because either you navigate to screen C from screen A directly. because every screen that you open was push in stack and if you use goBack() that function just pull last screen from stack and navigate you on that screen. Can you please share some more code where you are navigating into screens